# Entity framework select group by and sum

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm working on  ASP.NET and EF codefirst.
I want to find best-selling product with linq query
This is my selled products model

```
 public class FactorItem
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public int ProductId { set; get; }
        public int Count { set; get; } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to group by ProductId, then Sum the count and take the group with the highest sum:

```
var factorItems = DbContext.FactorItems
                           .GroupBy(f => f.ProductId)
                           .OrderByDescending(g => g.Sum(f => f.Count))
                           .FirstOrDefault()
                           .Key;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use linq to to find the result.

```
using(ctx = new Context())
{
   var maxValue = ctx.FactorItem.Max(e => e.Count);
   var result = ctx.FactoItem.Where(e => e.Count == maxValue);
}
```